# Removing extra zeros concatenated with the number in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I'm working with XSLT and trying to remove all zeros present before and after the numbers.
Examples:

**000000004552000** needs to translate to **4552**.

Any ideas how to get this done using xslt? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the expected result for input of `00010200`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please always say what XSLT version you are using.

In 2.0, you can use `replace(num, '^0+|0+$', '')`.

In 1.0, it's more difficult (everything is).

To remove leading zeroes, use `string(number(.))`.

To remove trailing zeroes, I think you need a recursive named template with the logic:

```
if $param mod 10 = 0 
then call yourself with param = $param div 10
else $param
```

Comment: Please don't ask specific people to answer specific questions. I'll choose which questions I want to answer.